# Django linking to page without putting data in URL

Tags: django

So I have a a HTML page with a table in it which contains details of a certain model. Each row contains details of a different object. I have a cell for a button as well.

Now, what I want is for the user to be able to click on the button and it should take them to the appropriate page for that particular user that they've clicked on. The way I can do this now is by creating a URL that takes a user_id argument along with a view to redirect it to a template. This url can then be added to the button. However, I don't want the user_id to be shown in the URL (being shown in Inspect Element is okay (as in the row ID)).

This rushed, so sorry. How can I do this?

Is there a way to do it without putting any information whatsoever in the URL?

Thank you!

Comment: If you are using the default mechanism for users in Django usernames should also be unique you can change urlpattern and the view for the user details to receive a username string instead of a id, after that, on displaying the links point to the username url instead of the id.

Comment: I'm using emails as the username, which are unique, except it looks messy to have a email in the URL. I'm not using the built in user system though.

Comment: It's not technically correct but can't you just use a POST request?

Comment: @Pictraz Is your main reason for not wanting them to show up in the URL that they look messy or are there more reasons behind it? (also, what are the reasons for the restriction to not having the ID shown in the URL?)

Comment: can you please clarify why you need the `user_id`?

Comment: @sthzg Partly because they look messy, and partly for security reasons. IDs may not be a big deal, but since it a small application I am writing, I don't want the user IDs to be open for viewing (since there are still some bugs that allow access to other data).

Comment: @dnozay I need to bring up the data of that particular user on a different page.

Comment: @Pictraz I see, but then I would strongly question the argument from the question, wherein it was okay if it showed up in the inspector. In general, if someone were interested in what data is exposed they wouldn't stop by looking at the URL (just my opinion).

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to send user ids from a POST instead of a GET for getting the user info, when the user clicks the button, you submit a hidden form which contains user_id (which you will update accordingly) and pass it to Django. On this POST call you will wire a render of the page for the user according to the POST parameter you are expecting containing the user id.

You can read the post parameters on a request via:

```
request.POST.get('user_id')
```

The downside of this approach is that you won't be able to share the link for a certain user, because the link will only contain the get parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can refactor your application to use some kind of SPA framework on the front-end. In this way you can load any content on your current page and the URL never changes if you don't want. Take a look for example at [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) or [Durandal](http://durandaljs.com/). Both works well with Django.

You can also solve the problem by using POST instead of GET but in my opinion that's not a very elegant solution because POST requests should be used just when you send data to the server.

Answer (score 0):

## creating urls

If the url is relevant to the user; then use the `user_id`; e.g. `http://example.com/mysite/users/<user_id>/userstuff`.

- obfuscation is not security.
- obfuscation is not a permission scheme.

Other possibilities:

- `http://example.com/mysite/users/<uniqueusername>/userstuff`.
- `http://example.com/mysite/users/<slug>/userstuff`.
- `http://example.com/mysite/users/<encoded>/userstuff`, where `encoded` is either 2-way encoding, or a field on the user model that is unique.

## getting logged in user  (`request.user`)

If the url has nothing to do with the user, but you need to get the authenticated user then read the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#authentication-in-web-requests.

```
def my_view(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        # use request.user
    else:
        # something else
```

Comment: I already have a way to get the logged in user. What I'm trying to do is visit a user's profile, but without specifying details about them in the URL. (if it's possible :P )

Comment: just use the `user_id`, I personally do not see a reason not use it. Workaround are to use `username` or `slug` or some kind of bidirectional encoding.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I'm thinking of going down the username route, if just for the URL :P

Answer (score 0):

If your worried about security I don't think keeping the user_id secret will be effective but if for some other reason you have to do this put it in session and redirect to user page without any parameters.

Put your table inside a form and store the id in an attribute of the button on each row:

```
<button class="mybutton" data-id="{{ my_object.id }}">view</button>
```

Put a hidden field at the bottom of your form:

```
<input type="hidden" id="user_id" name="user_id" />
```

Javascript:

```
$("table .mybutton").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#user_id").val($(this).attr("data-id"));
    $("#my_form").submit();
});
```

In your table view:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    request.session["user_id"] = request.POST.get('user_id')
    return redirect("user_page")
```

In your details view:

```
user_id = request.session["user_id"]
```